# Values being altered in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, enumerate

So I have a 2D numpy array (256,256), containing values between 0 and 10, which is essentially an image. I need to remove the 0 values and set them to NaN so that I can plot the array using a specific library (APLpy). However whenever I try and change all of the 0 values, some of the other values get altered, in some cases to 100 times their original value (no idea why).

The code I'm using is:

```
for index, value in np.ndenumerate(tex_data):
    if value == 0:
        tex_data[index] = 'NaN'
```

where tex_data is the data array from which I need to remove the zeros. Unfortunately I can't just use a mask for the values I don't need, as APLpy wont except masked arrays as far as I can tell.

Is there anyway I can set the 0 values to NaN without changing the other values in the array?

Comment: Are you sure this is based on your for loop? I tried for myself and have not observed this effect

Comment: Yup, I really don't know whats happening

Comment: Can you please provide some example code and data then? If we can't replicate, then we can't help O_O

Comment: What's the `dtype` of this array?  If it is a small int, trying to write a `NaN` string to it, or a float `np.nan` could produce problems (if it runs at all).

Answer (score 5):

Use fancy-indexing.  Like this:

```
tex_data[tex_data==0] = np.nan
```

I don't know why your original code was failing.  It looks correct to me, although terribly inefficient.

Comment: Note: `ndenumerate` does element-wise iteration. Index will be a 2D index, value will be that indices element.

Comment: Upvote for fancy indexing. The mantra with numpy is: Avoid for loops whenever you can!

Comment: Tried this and still produces the same problem?

Comment: Then you will have to provide sufficient code and/or data to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using float rules,

`tex_data/tex_data*tex_data`

make the job here also.